# Error en borrar '\\' en una String en la última iteración del bucle

Tags: c, string, bucles

estoy intentando hacer el comando **cd** del BASH utilizando **chdir()**, y estoy implementado la función **internal_cd_avanzado()** para tratar las **'\'**. Pero me imprime **un espacio demás** en la **última iteración**. Mi idea es que **ptrPath** vaya apuntando las **'\'** y borrarlo con **'\0'**, luego concatenarlo a **path**.

**Error:**

```
$ cd Prueba\ 1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6\ 7
Debug path: Prueba\ 1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6\ 7
Debug ': \
DEBUG path 0: Prueba 1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6\ 7
DEBUG path 1: Prueba 1 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6\ 7
DEBUG path 2: Prueba 1 2 3\ 4\ 5\ 6\ 7
DEBUG path 3: Prueba 1 2 3 4\ 5\ 6\ 7
DEBUG path 4: Prueba 1 2 3 4 5\ 6\ 7
DEBUG path 5: Prueba 1 2 3 4 5 6  7
Error internal_cd_avanzado(): chdir()
```

En el caso de un solo **'\'** va bien:

```
$ cd Prueba\ 1
Debug path: Prueba\ 1
Debug ': \
DEBUG path 0: Prueba 1
```

**Código:**

```
int internal_cd_avanzado(char **args) {
    // Crear un charArray vacio para guardar los argumentos
    char *const path = malloc((COMMAND_LINE_SIZE + 1) * sizeof(*path));

    int i = 1;  // saltarse el "cd"
    strcat(path, args[i++]);
    for (; args[i] != NULL; i++) {
        strcat(path, " ");
        strcat(path, args[i]);
    }
    printf("Debug path: %s\n", path);

    // Buscar caracter especial
    char *ptrPath;
    bool pathTratado = false;
    ptrPath = strchr(path, '\\');
    if (ptrPath && !pathTratado) {
        // Caso barra
        printf("Debug \': %c\n", '\\');
        int debug = 0;
        while (ptrPath) {
            *ptrPath = '\0';
            ptrPath++;
            strcat(path, ptrPath);
            printf("DEBUG path %d: %s\n", debug++, path);
            ptrPath = strchr(ptrPath, '\\');
        }
        pathTratado = true;
    }
    if (chdir(path)) {
        fprintf(stderr, ROJO_T "Error internal_cd_avanzado(): chdir()\n" RESET);
    }
    free(path);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No entiendo lo que estás intentando ¿No te vale recorrer el path y copiar en otro búfer sólo los caracteres que te valgan?